# How to convert from Mysql query to Codeigniter syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I just try to convert my my sql query to codeigniter syntax but i not able to do it

```
UPDATE tblUserController 
INNER JOIN tblUser on tblUserController.FK_userID  = tblUser.id
SET tblUserController.passwordWrong = 1, tblUserController.updatedAt = '2019-10-04 12:19:51'
WHERE  tblUserController.FK_userID = '2'
AND ( tblUserController.FK_loggedID = '1' OR tblUser.updatedAt < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
$sqlRawQuery = "UPDATE tblUserController 
INNER JOIN tblUser on tblUserController.FK_userID  = tblUser.id
SET tblUserController.passwordWrong = 1, tblUserController.updatedAt = '2019-10-04 12:19:51'
WHERE  tblUserController.FK_userID = '2'
AND ( tblUserController.FK_loggedID = '1' 
OR tblUser.updatedAt < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR) )
";
$this->db->query($sqlRawQuery);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert [raw query](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html) in codeigniter syntax like this :

```
$sql = "UPDATE tblUserController 
INNER JOIN tblUser on tblUserController.FK_userID  = tblUser.id
SET tblUserController.passwordWrong = 1, tblUserController.updatedAt = '2019-10-04 12:19:51'
WHERE  tblUserController.FK_userID = '2'
AND ( tblUserController.FK_loggedID = '1' OR tblUser.updatedAt < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR) )
";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

codeigniter is a php web framework, and SQL is a database query language. I believe you question requires rephrasing to include the wider intent of what you would like to  achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There is not direct method to convert MySQL Queries to CodeIgniter Syntax. But hey, you don't need to either. 
You can run MySQL Queries directly in CodeIgniter.

To submit a query, use the query function:

```
$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
```

But if you still need to change MySQL Queries to CodeIgniter Syntax, you can go through the [Query Builder Class of CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be your solution without translate your query to CI query builder.

```
$SQL = "SELECT bla bla bla...";
$query = $this->db->query($SQL);
return $query->result_array();
```